# Node.js/Express 404 error on POST to '/webhook'

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, stripe-payments

[image][image]For some reason I am getting a 404 error but only on when sending a post request to '/webhook' but I cannot figure out why. the rest of my post's are absolutely fine but I keep getting this message `[404] POST http://localhost:3001/webhook [evt_1IzeQ1EUG2WFNVaczcOMJWgu]`

Port 3001 is my client and my server is running on port 8080 (firebase emulator). Any idea what I could be doing incorrectly?

**index.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const { buffer } = require('micro');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');


const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

const serviceAccount = require("./permissions.json");

const firebaseAdmin = !admin.apps.length ? admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
}, 'firebaseAdmin') : admin.firebaseAdmin();


// api


// app config
const app = express();

// middlewares
app.use(cors({origin: true}));
app.use(express.json());

// api routes
app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send("hello world"));

app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (request, response) => {
  const { cart, email} = request.body;

  const transformedItems = cart.map(item => ({
    description: item.description === '' ? 'no description' : item.description,
    quantity: 1,
    price_data: {
      currency: 'usd',
      unit_amount: item.price * 100,
      product_data: {
        name: item.title,
      },

    }
  }));
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ['US']
    },
    line_items: transformedItems,
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${process.env.DOMAIN}/confirmation`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.DOMAIN}/sorry`,
    metadata: {
      email
    }
  });
  response.status(200).json({ id: session.id});
});


const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET;

const fulfillOrder = async (session) => {
  console.log('Fulfilling Booking', session);
  
  return firebaseAdmin
    .firestore()
    .collection('customers')
    .doc(session.metadata.email)
    .collection('orders')
    .doc(session.id).set({
      amount: session.amount_total / 100,
      timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`SUCCESS! Order #${session.id} has been added to the database!`);
    })
} 

app.post("/webhook", async (request, response) => {
  const requestBuffer = await buffer(request);
  const payload = requestBuffer.toString();
  const sig = request.headers("stripe-signature");

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('ERROR!!!', err.message);
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
    const session = event.data.object; 
    return fulfillOrder(session)
      .then(() => response.status(200))
      .catch((err) => response.status(400)
      .send(`Webhook error ${err.message}`));
  }
});


// listen command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app, firebaseAdmin);
```

Comment: Based on your screenshot, no services are running on Port 3001?

Answer (score 1):

To test Stripe webhooks locally (i.e. on localhost), you need to forward those webhook events to your localhost port. For that you need to install and configure the [Stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli). Once installed you can configure it using these commands:

```
stripe login

stripe listen --forward-to localhost:5001/webhook

// To manually trigger events using CLI
stripe trigger payment_intent.created
```

Because if you are triggering events from the dashboard they won't reach your localhost.

The port number should be the same as Cloud Functions emulator and the complete URL should match where your function is running. In you case, "http://localhost:5001/piers-laine/us-central1/api/webhook"

Comment: I have already done this and I get 2 messages. 1) payment_intent.created 2)
[404] POST http://localhost:3001/webhook it would appear my payment_intent works but none of my data's being set to my firestore database

Comment: @DylanWilliamson can you please share a screenshot of Firebase Emulator? I'd like to see the ports and logs.

Comment: I've added the screenshot to my post

Comment: @DylanWilliamson your functions emulator is running on port 5001. So the webhook URL should be `http://localhost:5001/webhook`

Comment: how would I go about this? I'm not entirely sure how to use a url over a relative path

Comment: @DylanWilliamson I didn't get that. Can you explain what do you mean? If you are using Stripe CLI, just forward the requests to localhost:5001/webhook

Comment: sorry I misunderstood but now I'm getting this [404] POST http://localhost:5001/webhook I'm honestly not sure what the issue is

Comment: @DylanWilliamson can you click on view logs in emulator and share a screenshot ?

Comment: @DylanWilliamson I think the URL of webhook should be `http://localhost:5001/piers-laine/us-central1/api/webhook` as per your screenshot. Can you please try forwarding stripe webhooks to this? Also moving this convo to a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233416/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-dylan-williamson).